How to align each bullet point in the table
Following this question. I have the following table:
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                            % not available on your system
%
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom


\usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font


\makeindex             % used for the subject index

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{8cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\ \hline
    \hline
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)
        \item Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk
        \item Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs
        \item Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk
        \item Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr
        \item Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork
        \item Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords
        \item Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork
        \item Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk
    \end{itemize}
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
    \label{tab:DTC}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}

I would like to align each bullet point in the table so that they are on the same row level as the corresponding points in the other column. For example, in the table above, I aim to align the four bullets in each column, noting that the last two bullets in the right column will not have corresponding bullets in the left column. As I am using a journal template, I prefer to make minimal changes to my code and avoid introducing new packages.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

What you like to get is possible if you insert each lists items in own row. Is this an option for you?

The requirement is to produce a table where each row contains a bullet point for each item, ensuring that the four items are aligned in the same row (appearing at the same level).

Are the svmult document class files available online? (They don't appear to be part of TeXLive.)

the first column has 4 bullet points, while the second has 6. How or where are the surplus two bullet points in column 2 supposed to be aligned?

Let's first what happens with svmult.
I removed the packages that aren't needed for the example, add them back for your document, with the exception of type1cm that's obsolete and useless as you use NewTX. Instead, I loaded lipsum just to add filler text.
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[21][1-2]
\item \lipsum[22][1-2]
\item \lipsum[23][1-2]
\item \lipsum[24][1-2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\ \hline
    \hline
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)
        \item Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk
        \item Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs
        \item Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk
        \item Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr
        \item Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork
        \item Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords
        \item Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork
        \item Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk
    \end{itemize}
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
\label{tab:DTC}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}


Now we see how svmult typesets itemized lists. Note the setting of the column widths so the table doesn't exceed the text width (that's 117mm, not 160mm).
OK, we can define a suitable local command for emulating itemized lists in your table.
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[21][1-2]
\item \lipsum[22][1-2]
\item \lipsum[23][1-2]
\item \lipsum[24][1-2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% local command
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{%
  \raggedright\let\\\tabularnewline
  \hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1
  \makebox[1.2em][l]{\textbullet}#1\deepstrut
}
\newcommand{\deepstrut}{\vspace{3pt}}

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\ \hline
\hline
\tabitem{Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)}
&
\tabitem{Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks 
  plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd 
  lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk}
\\
\tabitem{Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk}
&
\tabitem{Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr}
\\
\tabitem{Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs}
&
\tabitem{Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk
   pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork}
\\
\tabitem{Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd}
&
\tabitem{Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords}
\\
&
\tabitem{Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork}
\\
&
\tabitem{\let\deepstrut\relax Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
\label{tab:DTC}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}


To be honest, I'd prefer a more open look.
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[21][1-2]
\item \lipsum[22][1-2]
\item \lipsum[23][1-2]
\item \lipsum[24][1-2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% local command
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{%
  \raggedright\let\\\tabularnewline
  \hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1
  \makebox[1.2em][l]{\textbullet}#1
}

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{p{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\
\midrule
\tabitem Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)
&
\tabitem Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks 
  plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd 
  lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk
\\ \addlinespace
\tabitem Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk
&
\tabitem Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr
\\ \addlinespace
\tabitem Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs
&
\tabitem Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk
   pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork
\\ \addlinespace
\tabitem Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd
&
\tabitem Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords
\\ \addlinespace
&
\tabitem Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork
\\ \addlinespace
&
\tabitem \let\deepstrut\relax Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
\label{tab:DTC}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}


If you have several of these tables, you can use a special syntax. The command \doubleitemize takes four arguments:

the left header
the right header
the left items
the right items

Items in the third and fourth arguments are introduced by the usual \item; they are stored in two sequences, which are then equalized adding empty items and merged in a single sequence that will contain the “rows”. Finally we deliver everything.
The output is the same as in the “open look” image.
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doubleitemize}{mmmm}
 {
  \avi_doubleitemize:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_tl
\seq_new:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq
\seq_new:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq
\seq_new:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_double_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \avi_doubleitemize:nnnn
 {% #1 = left header, #2 = right header,
  % #3 = left items, #4 = right items
  % split the left items
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq { \item } {#3}
  % remove the empty item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % split the right items
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq { \item } {#4}
  % remove the empty item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % equalize the sequences
  \int_compare:nNnTF
   { \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq }
   >
   { \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq - \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq {}
     }
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq - \seq_count:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq {}
     }
   }
  % make the rows
  \seq_clear:N \l__avi_doubleitemize_double_seq
  \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN 
    \l__avi_doubleitemize_left_seq
    \l__avi_doubleitemize_right_seq
    \__avi_doubleitemize_row:nn
   % make the table
   \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{p{\dimeval{0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}}@{}}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{#1} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#2} \\
   \midrule
   \seq_use:Nn \l__avi_doubleitemize_double_seq { \addlinespace }
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__avi_doubleitemize_row:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__avi_doubleitemize_double_seq
   {
    \__avi_doubleitemize:n {#1} & \__avi_doubleitemize:n {#2} \\
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__avi_doubleitemize:n
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF {#1}
   {
    \raggedright\let\\\tabularnewline
    \hangindent=1.2em \hangafter=1 \scan_stop:
    \makebox[1.2em][l]{\textbullet} #1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[21][1-2]
\item \lipsum[22][1-2]
\item \lipsum[23][1-2]
\item \lipsum[24][1-2]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\doubleitemize
  {\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}}
  {\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}}
  {
   \item Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts
   \item Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk
   \item Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs
   \item Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd
  }
  {
   \item Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks 
     plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd 
     lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk
   \item Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr
   \item Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk
     pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork
   \item Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords
   \item Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork
   \item Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk
  }

\caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
\label{tab:DTC}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}


Thank you all for the wonderful answers. Is there a way to first add all the items that belong to the first column and then add all the items that belong to the second one afterwards?

@Avi Your wish is my command. See edit.

Here's a way to do it. Like Zarko wrote it's natural to construct the table row by row.
To do so, I use two \newcommands:

\otrb{}{} one table row BOTH
\otrr{} one table row RIGHT
which put text passed inside (many) itemize environments
this is the minimal change you'll introduce, and, off course, rewriting the tables content (i.e. doing some copy&paste)

You can also use conditionals inside a single macro to decide, which column has empty text, i.e. doesn't have to have an itemize environment. However, using two (or three) specialized macros is straight forward enough (and done quickly).
You can adjust spacing for the itemize environment as well known, e.g. from the Latex books.
I also commented out all packages not needed here AND replaced the missing documentclass by a standard.

%\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                            % not available on your system
%
%\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
%\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom


%\usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
%\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font


%\makeindex             % used for the subject index


% ~~~ one table row ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\otrb[2]{%
\begin{itemize}%
 \item #1%
\end{itemize}%
&%
\begin{itemize}%
 \item #2%
\end{itemize}%
}

\newcommand\otrr[1]{%
&%
\begin{itemize}%
 \item #1%
\end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\ \hline
    \hline
        \otrb{Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk}
            {Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks 
            plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on 
            q dkttrkbutkd lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk}\\
        \otrb{Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)}
            {Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr}\\
        \otrb{Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd}
            {Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork}\\
        \otrr{Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork}\\

    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccqztrzng}
    \label{tab:DTC}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}


Thanks @MS-SPO, your example works but I get the following warnings: (1) h' float specifier changed to ht'. (2) !h' float specifier changed to !ht'. (3) Font shape `OMS/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined (4) Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

@Avi - The first two warning messages are not specific to this answer. In fact, they arise because your code specifies [h] or [h!] instead of the more proper [ht] and [ht!].

What about: Font shape `OMS/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined (4) Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted

I see none of those messages PROVIDED I compile my posted code. If you reactivate all I've commented out, there may be problems. I assume they had been there before ... as I don't see any specific reason for them to arise. If your approach works (1 row, 2 lists) then mine will as well (1 or 2 lists per row). Having them wrapped in \newcommands doesn't change anything here.

Something like this?

\documentclass{article} %[graybox]{svmult}

\usepackage{type1cm} % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                     % not available on your system
\usepackage{makeidx}  % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx} % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                      % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol} % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{newtxtext}      
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{%
   >{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=0.667em%
     \textbullet\space}X}
     
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Fwkkld-Enwzyn Bvvplzjwnld}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{\textbf{Twqznlw-Enwryn Zzccqztrzng}} \\ 
    \midrule
    Qkcwzds fzhw trqnsqktmkr wktm kwo kqql qnd offkttkng kqtrkks (dkbktw qnd crrkdkts)
    &
    Rkcqrds qchk trqnsqktmkr wktm thrkk kqtrkks - thk trqdktkqnl dkbklk kqtrkks plus qn qddktkqonql dkqktktkq or rqkord qryptogrqqphkqllqllk rqkordkd on q dkttrkbutkd lkdgkr lkkk blkqkqhk \\ 
    \addlinespace
    Mqkntqkns thk qccountkng kquqtkqn thqt Qssets = Lkqbxltkks + Kquqtk
    &
    Thk thkrd kqtrk prqvkdks q sngklk, shqrkd, kmmutqblk rqkord on thk lkdgkr \\ 
    \addlinespace    
    Qntrlks qrk rqkqrkdd prkvqtkly kn q qompqny's own journqls qnd lkdggkrs
    &
    Lkdgkr prqvkdks trqnsplrknqy - qll kqtrkks qrk vkskblk to pkrmlsskqonk pqrtkqkpqnts on thk nkwork \\ 
    \addlinespace   
    Prqnk tq krrqrs qr posskbkktk kn mqnupulqtqon qs rqkkrds qqn bk qltkrrkdd
    &
    Rkdulks rksks of frqud, hkdndkn dkkqlkqngs, or mqnukqlly qltkrrkdd pqsq rqkords \\ 
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
    &
    Trqnsqktmns qqn bk vkrkfkd kn rqql-tkqk by knkpkndknt pqrtkks on thk nkwork \\ 
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
    &
    Qutmmtkd rqkqnkkllktqkqon skmplkfks qudktkng qnd kmprovks qomplkqnkk \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Fwnpqrrvqon of fwkkld-enwzyn bvvplzjwnld qnd twqznlw-enwryn zzccq\-ztrzng}
    \label{tab:DTC}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Yes Thanks. Is there a way to do it with less new packages and commands?

I can see absolutely no reason for refusing to employ the tabularx, ragged2e, and booktabs packages. All three have been around for decades and are very well debugged, and are used by thousands, if not tens of thousands, of LaTeX users. TeX and LaTeX are macro expansion packages. Having users define macros as shortcuts is not only ok, it's very much encouraged. Don't let the fear of the unknown paralyze you.
